# Trying to use Restkit on iOS - XCode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa, restkit

I am trying to use RestKit on my app, and currently using master on github as a git submodule. The whole thing is installed and running. However, when I try to get JSON data from my rails app, I am getting a BAD_EXC_ACCESS on RestKit, more specifically on RKObjectLoader.m, line 365.

```
if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(request:didLoadResponse:)]) {
    [_delegate request:self didLoadResponse:_response];
}
```

Not sure what is going on here but should I assume it is a problem with Restkit?

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
-(id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        RKObjectMapping* patientMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Patient class]];

        [patientMapping mapKeyPath:@"id" toAttribute:@"identifier"];
        [patientMapping mapKeyPath:@"first_name" toAttribute:@"first_name"];
        [patientMapping mapKeyPath:@"middle_initial" toAttribute:@"middle_initial"];
        [patientMapping mapKeyPath:@"last_name" toAttribute:@"last_name"];
        [patientMapping mapKeyPath:@"email" toAttribute:@"email"];
        [patientMapping mapKeyPath:@"password_hint_question" toAttribute:@"password_hint_question"];
        [patientMapping mapKeyPath:@"password_hint_answer" toAttribute:@"password_hint_answer"];

        [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setMapping:patientMapping forKeyPath:@"patients"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)loadAll {
    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/ios_patient.json" delegate:self];
}
```

So basically I instantiate this class and call loadAll. My ios_patient.json is returning the following JSON code:

```
{"patients": [{"id": 1, "first_name": "John", "last_name": "Appleseed", "email": "johnappleseed@apple.com"}]}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can enable NSZombieEnabled to get to know more about the crash or use malloc_history with process id.

Comment: Objective-C variables are typically named in camel case, for what it's worth. So you should probably double check that your "first_name" variable is defined as "NSString *firstName", and that your mapping is "[patientMapping mapKeyPath:@"firstName" toAttribute:@"first_name"];"

Comment: Also, 1. Are you sure you haven't released your delegate? 2. Are you using ARC? 3. Have you implemented the RKObjectLoader delegate methods (request:didLoadResponse:)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. It turns out RestKit is not compatible with ARC and yes, I was using it. The variables were properly mapped (even though they were not camelcase) and the delegates were being properly set and implemented as well. Good thing I am early in the development process and can get back to non ARC.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use ARC and RestKit, just set the -fno-objc-arc  on the RestKit files.